# Visual Studio, docker container->container call: Connection Refused

Tags: c#, docker, visual-studio, docker-compose

Edit: Problem reduced to appearing when changing from .Net6 to .Net8. Changing from .Net6 to .Net7 works fine. But why?

I've tried to follow this tutorial.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/tutorial-multicontainer?view=vs-2022

The have pushed their code to
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vs-tutorial-samples/tree/master/docker/ComposeSample

I download and it works.
I change .Net version of projects AND linux versions building/running the projects from .Net6 to .Net8 and I get Connection Refused calling WebApi.

It smells of more strict defaults, but I find it hard to pinpoint and fix.

### So: Can you download above sample and get it running for most recent .Net, currently .Net8? And of course I'd like to understand why this is/was a problem.

Older part of question:

I've got the WebFrontEnd running and attempting to call the WebApi. Upon calling the WebApi, the FrontEnd get Connection Refused.

The WebApi is running correctly when I point the browser to http://localhost:53845/Counter . I suspect the problem is that the WebApi is available on a different port than expected from WebFrontEnd. As I understand it, the WebFrontEnd expects to find the WebApi on port 80?

How can I debug the communication when it happens inside the docker environment?

Calling code:

```
using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
{
    // Call *mywebapi*, and display its response in the page
    var request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage();
    // webapi is the container name
    request.RequestUri = new Uri("http://webapi/Counter");
    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    string counter = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    ViewData["Message"] = $"Counter value from cache :{counter}";
}
```

Comment: My guess is that your webapi container is based on aspnet 8. Aspnet containers now listen on port 8080 rather than 80. Try using `http://webapi:8080/Counter` instead.

Comment: @HansKilian -- that was indeed the problem! Thanks! If you "elevate" the comment to an answer, I'll be happy to select it as the Solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using version 8 ASP.NET containers, the default port has changed from 80 to 8080.

If that's the case, you should use `http://webapi:8080/Counter` instead.

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/containers/8.0/aspnet-port).

Answer (score 1):

This is listed as a breaking change, which is logical as 80 is a privileged port. It should never have been 80.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/containers/8.0/aspnet-port

I find it clearer and to just specify ports yourself for which you have 3 options.

Specify "Urls" in appsettings.json

```
{
  "Urls": "http://0.0.0.0:30000"
}
```

code it into your startup pipeline or just directly

`.UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:30000")` or `app.Urls.Add("http://0.0.0.0:30000")`

set environment variable in your container with ENV

`ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://0.0.0.0:30000`